# About Flex with PHP kick start

Tags: php, apache-flex

I am a php developer and I wish to start an application with a php flex combination. Can anyone direct me to a good tutorial/sample other than zend tutors.

Since I am working with Drupal I have no idea about zend concepts.

Do I need to know actionscript to start flex?

Thanks in advance,
Gobi :)

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about flex but iam a php developer but my flex friends told me to go throught this book **Foundation Flex for Developers:Data-Driven Applications with PHP, ASP.NET, ColdFusion, and LCDS** by publishers friendsofed. this book provide the think what you are looking for.

Comment: thanxs jaison :) have a nice day